# 3D Printing posts do not onebox in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, domain-names

Posting a link to a post on 3D Printing site, for example  `https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/5736`, does not produce a onebox in chat.

I suppose it's because the chat does not expect there could be digits in site names.

Comment: [This is not an April Fool's joke.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6822729#6822729)

Comment: Area51 links *do* onebox though: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6823343#6823343

Comment: @Glorfindel Interesting. So do [cs50.se] links. Maybe the _first_ character being a digit is the issue.

Comment: Is there any idea of if and when this might be fixed? It would make [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room) a bit more functional. Obviously it isn't essential, but it *would* be very nice to having it working correctly.